# How can I switch from rollup/vite to webpack for sveltekit?

Tags: webpack, svelte, sveltekit

The node polyfill isn't working for us on rollup/vite. We need to switch to webpack.

Is there any official documentation on how to use sveltekit with webpack?

Here is our `svelte.config.js` file:

```
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-static';
import preprocess from 'svelte-preprocess';
import path from 'path';
// import { NodeGlobalsPolyfillPlugin } from '@esbuild-plugins/node-globals-polyfill';
import dotenv from 'dotenv-flow';

dotenv.config();
const config = {
    preprocess: preprocess(),
    kit: {
        adapter: adapter({
            // default options are shown
            pages: 'build',
            assets: 'build',
            fallback: 'index.html',
            precompress: false
        }),
        vite: {
            optimizeDeps: {
                esbuildOptions: {
                    // Node.js global to browser globalThis
                    define: {
                        global: 'globalThis'
                    }
                    // Enable esbuild polyfill plugins
                    // plugins: [
                    //  NodeGlobalsPolyfillPlugin({
                    //      buffer: true,
                    //      global: true,
                    //      process: true,
                    //      url: true,
                    //      assert: true,
                    //      crypto: true,
                    //      http: true,
                    //      https: true,
                    //      os: true,
                    //      stream: true
                    //  })
                    // ]
                }
            },
            resolve: {
                alias: {
                    $components: path.resolve('./src/components'),
                    $stores: path.resolve('./src/stores'),
                    $api: path.resolve('./src/api'),
                    $node: path.resolve('./node_modules')
                }
            },
            build: {
                minify: false
            }
        }
    }
};

export default config;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't switch it. SvelteKit is highly dependent on Vite—so much so it's possible it'll even be shipped as a Vite plugin *at some point*.

If you really exhausted your options with Vite and decided you must use Webpack, an option would be to isolate all the code that requires it into a separate package which you can then prebundle with Webpack and consume from the SvelteKit app.

Comment: does sveltekit use esbuild for `npm run build` and something else for `npm run dev`?

Comment: it appears `NodeGlobalsPolyfillPlugin` is ignored when doing `npm run build`. This is why we were considering webpack instead.